# When to Thread. When not to Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm new to the idea of Threading, but not asynchronous behavior. My Android app is taking ~180 millisecond to start up and ~550 milli when I use GoogleAnalytics trackViewPage method and MobFoxView constructor. Coming from Actionscript 3, anything that "took time" was automatically async and I was forced to handle it with listeners which is a bit different in Android it appears. It seems **I'M** responsible for deciding when something should be asynchronous. So I guess my question is, **HOW** do I decide what should be async? Is it by milliseconds of executing? But perhaps that changes greatly between devices. Perhaps it should be by ... or is it by ....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know one important thing - by default everything you do without starting separate thread is executed on "main" thread (also knows as UI-thread).

If you do something, which can block - your UI will lag and users will suffer.

If you doing something, which is not about UI but about database query, network call or potentially **long blocking** operation - you need to start thread directly or use AsyncTask.

Also you must note, if you try to do something with UI (e.g. set value to a TextView) from not-main thread you will fail. UI can be acessed only from UI-Thread.